# Род аббревиатур

Tags: аббревиатуры

Есть такие аббревиатуры, которые воспринимаются нами уже как самостоятельные слова. Например, НЛО, ООН, США и т.д.
Но тогда встает вопрос: какого рода эти слова? То есть, понятно, что род определяет существительное, зашифрованное в аббревиатуре, но ведь часто мы уже и не помним расшифровку. И поэтому же часто можно услышать, например, "прилетело НЛО". То есть, получается, что род тут употребляется просто по аналогии: раз заканчивается на "о", значит, средний.
Так имеют ли такие общеупотребительные аббревиатуры свой род, или все-таки надо всякий раз вспоминать расшифровки?

Comment: Иногда надо вспоминать, иногда не надо... Вот МИД, например, мужского рода.

Answer (score 2):

Правило  определения рода аббревиатур по опорному слову соблюдается не всегда.

1) Аббревиатуры на твердый согласный   относятся к  м.роду, если они являются общеупотребительными: БАМ, МИД, Газпром, Минздрав. Но: новая ЛЭП (линия электропередач).

2) Аббревиатуры на О чаще относятся к среднему роду, даже если опорное слово не является сущ. ср. рода, например: НЛО, СИЗО, ГОЭРЛО.

Лишь некоторые аббревиатуры сохраняют род опорного слова м. или ж. рода: СПО (союз потребительских обществ) - м.р., ГКО (государственная краткосрочная облигация) - ж.р., ПРО (противоракетная оборона) - ж.р.

Также НАТО, ЮНЕСКО (ср.род) - русскими буквами переданы иностранные  названия.