# Как называется изменение рода для аббревиатур (род отличен от опорного слова)?

Tags: терминология, аббревиатуры, род

Как называется изменение рода для аббревиатур (род отличен от опорного слова)?

Пример:

> ЕПД - единый платёжный документ
>
> Создать корректный единый платёжный документ (мужской род)
>
> Получить простое или долговое ЕПД (средний род)

Вопрос уже поднимался [здесь (Род аббревиатур)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38807/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80) о правиле определения рода, но как называется это явление там не обозначено.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, речь идет **о морфологизации аббревиатур по роду.**  В этом случае род определяется по  форме полученного слова (конечный гласный или согласный звук), а  не по  исходному смысловому значению (то есть по опорному слову).

Род звуковой инициальной аббревиатуры (читаемой «по слогам») зависит не только от рода опорного слова, но и от внешнего фонетического облика аббревиатуры, точнее – от ее концовки. **Так, если аббревиатура оканчивается на согласный, то она может согласовываться по мужскому роду, несмотря на принадлежность опорного слова к женскому или среднему роду.** Причем в некоторых случаях согласование по мужскому роду является единственно возможным. Например, только мужского рода слова вуз (хотя заведение), МИД (хотя министерство), загс (хотя запись). [Как правильно употреблять аббревиатуры? | gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=60)